# How does a TVS absorb voltage?

Tags: voltage, tvs

I cant understand how a TVS might absorb voltage. As far as I can see, when a transient is applied to it, it becomes a very small resistor, so the transient voltage will still be on top of him, but all the current will flow through it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an ideal circuit with a perfect voltage source and no parasitic resistance, you would be right -- even if the transient voltage suppressor (TVS) conducts 100 A of current the damaging voltage would still be present on other components.

It's the parasitic effects that let the TVS work.  There is resistance and inductance in the traces, vias, and pins, and there is capacitance at various points (bypass capacitors placed on the PCB, internal bypass capacitance on an IC, parasitic capacitance).  All of this means that when the voltage is **briefly** too high at the TVS, it will not immediately be so high at the downstream circuits.

Of course, if you force an overvoltage condition for long enough, it will still damage the circuits, but that would no longer qualify as a "transient voltage" to be suppressed.

[image: CircuitLab Schematic evf59b]

Comment: I think you should also (or even primarily) include the parasitics (which are sometimes introduced on purpose) on the spike source. This is the main reason why TVS (and also decoupling capacitors and other power line filters) are able to smooth the voltage.

Comment: @jpc - Yes, the source (parasitic) impedance is the most important part of figuring out how quickly and to what level the voltage will fall.  My answer here is explaining how it is possible for any component to protect at all without having a series component after it.  This is the main confusion I had when I first used a TVS.

Comment: @Justin so as far as I can see, you cant really say that the TVS will clamp the voltage, because the parasitic inductance could charge if its big enough and the source is strong enough, right?
Since the inductor will charge proportional to di/dt, but the whole current will flow through the TVS, it will not charge much....
correct me please if I am saying rubbish

Comment: @mFeinstein - I'm not sure what you mean by charging an inductor. I would think of it more like as an instantaneous step in the voltage across the inductor will cause the current through the inductor to start increasing (di/dt = V/L).  This inductance is quite small since it is parasitic, so it will start conducting quickly (di/dt will be large when a voltage step is applied at the input). Hopefully that delay and the delays due to the shunt capacitance still give the TVS enough time to dissipate the energy.

Comment: @Justin I meant "charging" like the way it stores magnetic energy in it`s field, just like a capacitor stores energy in its electrical field.
Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

A TVS becomes a very low resistance when the voltage across it is sufficient to cause the device to break down and conduct.

This affords protection in a few ways:

1. If the transient is for a short duration and is within the energy handling capability of the TVS, the TVS breaks down and becomes a small resistance. This will limit the voltage at the TVS for the reasons described in Justin's answer - parasitic circuit elements essentially form a voltage divider with the TVS.
2. If the transient is for a longer duration, the TVS clamps and the low resistance should draw sufficient current to blow the input fuse / circuit breaker (without blowing the TVS) which isolates the load from the source.

Of course, if the transient is for a long duration and is *not* within the energy handling capability of the TVS (or the TVS current cannot interrupt the fuse/breaker) the TVS clamps and the low resistance draws sufficient current to blow the TVS.

Answer (score 1):

TVS clamps voltage.  If the Maximum Reverse Current is not exceeded, the voltage will not exceed the Maximum Reverse Voltage.  (I'll be referring to this typical [TVS datasheet](http://www.bourns.com/data/global/pdfs/SMAJ.pdf).)

Let's look at an example of a transient, which has: has a high voltage, short duration, limited energy.  (ESD fits these criteria.)  **This transient is not modeled as an ideal voltage source.**  If you short this transient to ground through a TVS, the latter will adsorb the energy of the transient.  The [TVS datasheet](http://www.bourns.com/data/global/pdfs/SMAJ.pdf) usually shows Peak Pulse Power dissipation.

TVS also has a rating for continuous power dissipation (which is much smaller than the Peak Pulse Power).  If there is a need to protect against a DC overvoltage (long duration, not just a transient), the TVS is usually used with a resistor or a fuse, which would limit the current.  In case of a DC overvoltage, a Zener TVS can be viewed like a regular Zener diode.

Answer (score 1):

If the surge protector is a diode, then it has a fixed voltage drop. This means that the rest of the high voltage is dropped elsewhere, namely across the source from which that voltage originates.

If the surge protector is a varistor, then how it works is that it develops a low resistance through which the surge current can pass. This also reduces the voltage of the voltage spike if the varistor's voltage is lower than the source voltage. The high voltage has to drop across the source impedance, and across the varistor. This forms a voltage divider, which cuts the voltage spike according to the ratio of the varistor's resistance to the total resistance.

The voltage spike is not a stiff voltage source which is unaffected by the resistance of the protecting device: it cannot develop its full voltage into arbitrarily low impedances.

Answer (score 0):

Applying high voltages to a circuit is bad because it causes large currents to flow into the circuit.  If the TVS is a very low resistance, the current will flow through the TVS instead of anything else.  Hence anything else will be protected.